# Bluetooth Devices without pairing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-bluetooth

I am creating a app in which a user enables its Bluetooth device from which I am getting its android id and mac address I want to save the list of all the available Bluetooth devices it come in contact with, without pairing to the device.

I want to save the list is it possible to get list of mac address and android id of other user whose Bluetooth is on/Activate/Enabled but is not paired with my device. I just want the list that I come through all this Bluetooth devices.

Little code of my bluetooth getting on and toasting MAC address and unique android id

```
 public void bluetooth(){
        final BluetoothAdapter bAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if(bAdapter == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth Not Supported",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            if(!bAdapter.isEnabled()){
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE),1);


                imei_string1 = bAdapter.getAddress();
                String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

                Log.d("Android","Android ID : "+android_id);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),imei_string1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"My andorid ID is"+android_id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                // If there are paired devices
                if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                    // Loop through paired devices
                    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                        Log.e("Mac Addressess", "are:  " + bAdapter.getRemoteDevice(device.getAddress()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: please post your current code

Comment: i have posted liltte code of my working bluetooth from which i am geeting unique id and Mac address but i want to get list of all devices which is not paired with my device

Comment: Doesn't a Bluetooth device have to be explicitly in a scanning mode to find new devices? I assume that has to come from a user action, and it cannot do that on a long-term basis (it would wear the battery down, and the privacy implications would be enormous).